# Android: how to make your phone's camera LED flash when receiving calls, messages, or notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications, flashlight

i am developing an app that will running in background every time. now i want a feature like if user receive phone or message or any notification then flash light should flash till phone rings or vibrating.

i am using below coding to turn on flash light

```
// Turning On flash
private void turnOnFlash() {
 if (!isFlashOn) {
     if (camera == null || params == null) {
         return;
     }
     // play sound
    // playSound();
     params = camera.getParameters();
     params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
     camera.setParameters(params);
     camera.startPreview();
     isFlashOn = true;

     // changing button/switch image
  //   toggleButtonImage();
 }

}
```

but flash light is not turning on

and below code to get camera

```
private void getCamera() {
 if (camera == null) {
     try {
         camera = Camera.open();
         params = camera.getParameters();
     } catch (RuntimeException e) {
         Log.e("Camera Error. Failed to Open. Error: ", e.getMessage());
     }
 }
}
```

is this code .. the logcat print the exception and said `cannot connect to camera service`. so in flashturnOn class camera gets null and it returns and end the class without flashlight turn on

Thanxxx for any help

Comment: sorry @SuvenduShekharGiri .. im looking for starting idea. i google a lot but cant get any help

Comment: Check out https://github.com/CUTR-at-USF/walk-bright.  This app simply starts periodically flashing the screen and flash when you start it up.

Answer (score 1):

Best way of starting would be trying code used for making a flashlight app like [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/04/android-developing-flashlight-application/)
For turning on:

```
  params = camera.getParameters();
    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    camera.setParameters(params);
    camera.startPreview();
```

for turning off

```
params = camera.getParameters();
    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    camera.setParameters(params);
    camera.stopPreview();
```

Comment: thnxxx .. the main thing is to know phone is ringing .. how to this ?

Comment: http://androidexample.com/Incomming_Phone_Call_Broadcast_Receiver__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=61&aaid=86 < should help you